# Showing video frames side by side after decoding (Android)

Tags: android, rgb, framebuffer, android-mediacodec, yuv

Given two encoded streams, I want to join them side by side. As in assume I have two separate H.264 encoded 1024x768 videos with the same frame rate. I want to combine those two such that video 1 and video 2 are side by side to form a stream double the width (1024*2)x768 or 2048x768. My first take was to decode the stream and combine the individual frames then reencode the single stream. Decoding and reencoding are fine and this works however it's extremely slow (as is ffmpeg). The issue it seems is with the computational time to convert frames from YUV to RGB or to combine them in their YUV form. The Android decoder produces YUV and the math used to combine frames side by side is intensive for that form. So my question is;

1) is there a quicker or more efficient way to combine frames if they are in YUV form?

2a) if not, is it much faster computationally to combine them if they are in RGB form instead?

2b) if so, how would I decode an H.264 stream into RGB frames in Android?

P.S. Tried ffmpeg and openCV both require the YUV to RGB conversion which makes it extremely slow (~5fps)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the API or the command line?

Comment: API but used command line when testing with ffmpeg

Comment: The quickest way would be to create the YUV buffers large enough for both frames and copy the data yourself before passing it to the encoder without the need to convert back and forth to RGB.

Comment: That makes sense. However, I think due to the nature of YUV I cannot bulk copy and paste (ie. memcpy) the whole frame, I'll need to do it in an interleaving way which I think is a big issue in terms of efficiency/speed

Comment: You could also use inline assembler to speed things up for copying from 2 frames. Very likely much quicker than memcpy or a C function.

Comment: How much faster is it? Just curious. So the solutions are: Your solution to use inline assembler OR have the codec decode the frame to RGB then I can do easy bulk copy/pastes. For the latter, do you know how to force Android's codec to decode to RGB instead of YUV?

Comment: Not having done ARM assembly it would probably be easier to test the functionality and speed using C. And assume the buffers are 4 byte width (ie 1024 is) so that the copying of the data is faster than copying bytes. There is huge overhead converting YUV to RGB so I would stick with YUV.

Comment: So how would you combine the frames if they are in YUV format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decoded frame AVFrame has `uint_t *data[]` and `int linesize[]` in the structure. A YUV frame has three data pointers and three linesizes. Quite often the line sizes are greater than the width so take care to allow for that.

Here's some psuedo code that may help. Hopefully without too many typo's.

```
// No proper checks in here, it's just for reference
// You could just as easily pass the data pointers for the outframe as uint8_t *data[]

void mergeFrames(AVFrame *frame1, AVFrame *frame2, AVFrame *outframe)
{
    // do Y frame
    uint32_t *out = outframe->data[0]; // 1 and 2 are for the U and V frames

    uint8_t *in1 = frame1->data[0];
    uint8_t *in2 = frame2->data[0];

    int height = outframe->height;
    int inwidth = frame1->width;
    int stride = frame1->linesize[0];
    int pos = 0;

    while (pos++ < height) {
        // left side

        uint32_t *in = (uint32_t*)(in1 + pos * stride); // <- stride, not width

        int c = frame1->width >> 2; // assume 4 bytes
        while (c--) *out++ = *in++;

        // right side

        in = (uint32_t*)(in2 + pos * stride);

        c = width >> 2;
        while (c--) *out++ = *in++;
    }

    // And the same for the U and V frames
}
```

The compiler should do a good job of optimising it.

Also note that when working with the U and V frames, they are half the width and half the height of the Y frame.

Comment: Will try this and report back!

Comment: So this kind of works... The result is the frames side by side however it's fully tinted with green instead

Comment: If it is green then one of the U or V frames isn't being copied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What complex math is needed in order to combine these images?

All you need to do is to copy each line from frameOfVideo1 to indexes 0 to 1023 and each line from frameOfVideo2 to indexes 1024 to 2047.
(of the line of the combined image)

(these are the indexes for the y plane. the u,v planes or uv plane (e.g. nv12) the numbers are different. but the concept is the same)

Comment: My understanding is what you described is relevant to RGB and that is why it's easy but for YUV it's more complex and requires more math than just a simple bulk copy